# Error in .doLoadActions

Tags: r, rcpp

I have an `Rcpp` based R package which when checked by `devtool::check()` produces following warning:

> Error in .doLoadActions(where, attach) :    error in load action .**A**.1 for package tarantoolr: (function (ns) : could not find function "loadModule"

What might be the cause of such behavior and what is the best way to fix this issue?

Full build and check log from [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/thekvs/tarantoolr) can be viewed [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/128552201/log.txt), warnings are located around lines 1212 and 1223.

Package itself is located at [Github](https://github.com/thekvs/tarantoolr).

Comment: Please add the up-to-date version of your code to GitHub (create a dev-branch) that is causing travis-ci to error.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your package using `devtools::check(document = FALSE)` as I think your `NAMESPACE` file is being overwritten and made "empty" as you do not use `roxygen2` to create the necessary entries

e.g. You need to create a file called **tarantoolr-package.R** that contains:

```
#' @importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
#' @useDynLib(tarantoolr)
#' @exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
#' @details
#' We all live in a yellow submarine.. 
"_PACKAGE"
```

Without this file, again, the `NAMESPACE` file is empty and, thus, the global export of all function via `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` does not occur. Hence, there are no known functions within the environment.